# Using MYDBR login tables with Agile auth

Tags: php, authentication, agile, atk4

Im currently using the Agile Toolkit to create my website, and in this website we are including reporting, which is being handled by MYDBR. MYDBR includes its own login tables, and I was hoping that I could integrate agile to use this login table instead of my custom one so the users didnt need to remember two different logins. However Im not totally sure how I could go about integrating these two systems to use the same user login database. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use myDBR's Single Sign-On functionality. It allows for you to use external system for user authentication. Just see the documentation how to set it up: [myDBR Single Sign-On](http://mydbr.com/doc/?prefs.sso.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with MYDBR, but I believe you can somehow create new model in ATK4 which will use connection to MYDBR and it's user table.
If you somehow can do that, then you can use this model in Auth class for authorization.